# Do I have to request access to a product too?

Tags: linkedin-api, product

My client wants to display his company's recent LinkedIn posts on his website.  I plan on working up a custom PHP script to make that happen. I created an app and it's been verified.  Do I need to request access to one of the Products too?  Based on the choices, the 'Pages Data Portability API' product seems to be the right fit, but is this necessary?  It seems like a lot of hoops to jump through. I'm not building some enterprise level SAAS, just a simple script for one client.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

I setup an app and verified it.  I'm led to believe I need to request access to a product but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to request access from Linkedin to scrape their data or use their API. It is in their terms of service.